Different translations for different sites
I am building a directory engine with Django. It will be used on different domains, such as houses.com and games.com etc.
There's a button on the header, which is 'Add Item' which redirects to item creation page. It's wrapped with {% trans %} tag. But I want translation of that button to be "Add your house" on houses.com and "Add Your Game" on games.com.
What is best practice for doing that?
I was expecting to find a solution for that.

You add a contextual marker [Django-doc]. Indeed, we can for example have:
{% translate "Add item" context site_name %}
and in the translation file (.po):
msgctxt "houses.com"
msgid "Add item"
msgstr "Add house"

msgctxt "games.com"
msgid "Add item"
msgstr "Add game"
Now the only problem is how to onject a site_name variable in all templates? We can do this with a context processor [Django-doc]. We can define such context processor like:
# some_app/context_processors.py

from django.conf import settings


def with_site_name(request):
    return {'site_name': getattr(settings, 'SITE_NAME', None)}
then we configure the context processor, and add a SITE_NAME in settings.py:
# settings.py

# …

SITE_NAME = 'games.com'

# …

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # …
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'some_app.context_processors.with_site_name'
            ],
        },
    },
]

# …
